# Difference between RSA PEM file contents and output of pkey command

Tags: openssl, rsa, pem

I recently got tripped up believing that since the `cat` output of an RSA public key is identical to the output of `openssl pkey -in my-pub-key.pem -pubin`, that the same would apply to the private key. It does not. Why not?

The contents of the private key file have 'RSA PRIVATE KEY' header and footer, and I see the '==' characters at the end often used for padding, IIUC.

The output of `openssl pkey -in my-priv-key.pem` has a different header and footer ('RSA' is missing) and the encoded content is different, not ending in '==' though ironically the first 4 characters are the same.

Why the difference?

Comment: What you get from `cat` of a public key is of course dependent on what is in the file :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the difference between the PKCS#1 format (specific to RSA keys, hence the extra `"RSA"`) compared with PKCS#8 format (generic keys, where the RSA indication is encoded in the binary). If PKCS#8 encoded contains an RSA key then it has the same PKCS#1 binary structure inside of it.

You can have a look at the ASN.1 encoded contents by pasting the base 64 encoded binary into e.g. [this JavaScript based encoder](https://lapo.it/asn1js/), or you could feed it into `openssl asn1parse` command.

Normally you'd use the PEM format *without* the "RSA" in the identifier for maximum compatibility.